# Failed to start wildfly 8.0, Message CHARACTERS, expected START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

We are migrating JBoss 5.1 to WildFly 8.2. Here I tried by developing a sample application using JBoss 5.1 and trying to deploy the same on WildFly 8.2.The project is deployed successfully in 5.1 and failed in WildFly 8.2, it is created EJBJPAExample.jar.failed file.

The below is the stack trace while running WildFly

```
Calling "D:\Migration_Workspace\Jboss\Jboss-8\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "D:\Migration_Workspace\Jboss\Jboss-8\wildfly-8.2.0.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pk
gs=org.jboss.byteman"

===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
17:12:34,600 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
17:13:20,638 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
17:13:20,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" starting
17:14:28,350 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (manage
ment-http)
17:15:06,125 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.3.0.Final
17:15:06,161 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Final
17:15:06,210 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
17:15:06,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:15:06,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:15:06,238 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 4 core t
hreads with 32 task threads based on your 2 available processors
17:15:06,242 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
17:15:06,209 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. P
lease make sure it is unique.
17:15:06,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
17:15:06,326 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.0.Final starting
17:15:06,348 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.0.Final starting
17:15:06,435 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.6.Final
17:15:06,781 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
17:15:06,807 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:15:06,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.9.Final)
17:15:06,842 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant d
river class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
17:15:06,858 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.21.Final
17:15:07,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h
2
17:15:07,457 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path D:\Migrati
on_Workspace\Jboss\Jboss-8\wildfly-8.2.0.Final/welcome-content
17:15:07,485 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
17:15:07,502 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
17:15:07,601 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for di
rectory D:\Migration_Workspace\Jboss\Jboss-8\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\standalone\deployments
17:15:07,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "EJBJPAExample.jar" (runtim
e-name: "EJBJPAExample.jar")
17:15:07,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ejbjpa
17:15:07,772 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBJPAEx
ample.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBJPAExample.jar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to pr
ocess phase PARSE of deployment "EJBJPAExample.jar"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final
.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1
.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Fina
l]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,6]
Message: found: CHARACTERS, expected START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT
        at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ds.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final
.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,6]
Message: found: CHARACTERS, expected START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:1254) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
        at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.v10.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:161)
        at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.v10.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:124)
        at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.v10.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:87)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ds.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:89)
        ... 6 more

17:15:08,237 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0
.0.1:8280
17:15:08,617 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3
.2.Final
17:15:08,899 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datas
ources/ExampleDS]
17:15:09,345 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - addres
s: ([("deployment" => "EJBJPAExample.jar")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBJPAExamp
le.jar\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBJPAExample.jar\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed t
o process phase PARSE of deployment \"EJBJPAExample.jar\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,6]
Message: found: CHARACTERS, expected START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,6]
Message: found: CHARACTERS, expected START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT"}}
17:15:09,453 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "EJBJPAExample.jar" (runtime-name : "EJBJPA
Example.jar")
17:15:09,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBJPAExample.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartExce
ption in service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBJPAExample.jar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "EJBJPAExample.ja
r"

17:15:09,613 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190/manage
ment
17:15:09,616 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190
17:15:09,627 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 155428ms - Star
ted 187 of 238 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 82 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
17:15:09,728 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EJBJPAExample.jar (runtime-name
: EJBJPAExample.jar) in 9ms
17:15:09,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "EJBJPAExample.jar" (runtime-name: "EJBJPAE
xample.jar")
17:15:09,879 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBJPAExample.jar".PARSE
```

Comment: What's the problem here? What question are you asking? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We are migrating jboss 5.1 to wildfly8, here I tried by developing a sample application using jboss 5.1 and trying to deploy the same on wildfly 8.The project is deployed successully in 5.1 and failed in wildfly 8, it is created EJBJPAExample.jar.failed file. The above is the stack trace while running the jboss wildfly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is complaining about one of the XML files in your document which has character data at row 3, column 6 where it expects an element.

The root cause is very likely the fact that you're trying to deploy an EJB project which works on JBoss 5.1 onto WildFly. EJB 2.1 is not supported on WildFly, so you won't be able to just deploy the same project without any changes.